# TSQL: Trying to turn joined select statement into update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Not the most complex problem but I've been looking at this one for a while and I'm at a block. Here is a TSQL select statement I want to turn into an update statement. The table structures are included for reference (server, db, and table names simplified from what they actually are).

```
SELECT m.ConfirmationCode as CodeInMain,
       e.ConfirmationCode as CodeInEvents
FROM Server1.DB1.dbo.MainTable AS m
     INNER JOIN Server2.DB1.dbo.Events AS e ON c.AccountCode = e.AccountCode
                                             AND c.Commodity = ( 
                                                    SELECT Alias
                                                    FROM Server2.DB1.dbo.Commodities
                                                    WHERE pkCommodityId = e.fkCommodityId )
WHERE m.AccountCode = e.AccountCode
  AND m.Brand IN( 'FTR', 'CER' );
```

Here are the referenced table schemas:

```
Server1.DB1.dbo.MainTable (ConfirmationCode varchar(100), AccountCode varchar(100), Commodity varchar(1), Brand varchar(3))

Server2.DB1.dbo.Events (ConfirmationCode varchar(100), AccountCode varchar(100), Commodity int)

Server2.DB1.dbo.Commodities (pkCommodityId int, Alias varchar(100))
```

Server 2 is linked to Server 1.

The current output of the select statement is:

```
CodeInMain | CodeInEvents
--------------------------
AN235cAc0a |    NULL
CSORSX239c |    NULL
...
```

All of my outputted information is as expected.

My goal is to update `e.ConfirmationCode as CodeInEvents` with the data in `m.ConfirmationCode as CodeInMain` but I am getting stuck on how to accommodate for the join. I realize that a cursor can be used to cycle through the contents of the above output when stored in a temporary table, but I would really like to be able to do this in a single update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has a non-ANSI extended `UPDATE` syntax that supports `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE e
SET e.ConfirmationCode = m.ConfirmationCode
FROM Server1.DB1.dbo.MainTable AS m
     INNER JOIN Server2.DB1.dbo.Events AS e ON c.AccountCode = e.AccountCode
                                             AND c.Commodity = ( 
                                                    SELECT Alias
                                                    FROM Server2.DB1.dbo.Commodities
                                                    WHERE pkCommodityId = e.fkCommodityId )
WHERE m.AccountCode = e.AccountCode
  AND m.Brand IN( 'FTR', 'CER' );
```

Comment: Awesome, looks like we arrived at very similar solutions around the same time. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

got it.

```
Update e
set e.ConfirmationCode = m.ConfirmationCode
from Server2.DB1.dbo.Events e
inner join Server1.DB1.dbo.MainTable m on m.AccountCode = e.AccountCode and m.Commodity = (select Alias from Server2.DB1.dbo.Commodities where pkCommodityId = e.fkCommodityId)
where m.AccountCode = e.AccountCode and m.Brand in ('FTR', 'CER')
```